# Svelte Reactive Value with Typescript Type

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm trying to get a timestamp from a Date object in Svelte and TypeScript. I want the timestamp to update whenever the Date object is updated, so I'm trying to make it reactive. Here's the code I tried:

```
let date: Date = new Date();
$: timestamp: string = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ":" + 
    date.getSeconds(); // timestamp in format hh:mm:ss
```

But I'm getting this error from TypeScript: `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`. If I remove the type, then everything works. I think multiple meanings of a colon is confusing the compiler but I'm not sure. Is there any way I can do this while keeping the type?

Comment: You're overdoing type definitions. TypeScript will infer the types. Just do `let date = new Date(); $: timestamp = date.getHours() + ... + date.getSeconds();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason to do this in your case, since TypeScript will infer the type `string`.

However per the [Svelte TypeScript docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#how-do-i-type-reactive-assignments--i-get-an-implicitly-has-type-any-error), if you ever need to do this with a more complex type, do this:

```
let timestamp: string;
$: timestamp = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ":" + 
    date.getSeconds(); // timestamp in format hh:mm:ss
```